# For $0<a<b$, prove that $1-\frac{a}{b}<\ln (\frac{b}{a})<\frac{b}{a}-1$

Tags: calculus

I tried to answer this question for a few hours, without any success.

I would appreciate if you helped me with the following task:

$$\text{For }\,0<a<b,\, \text{ prove that }\,\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)<\ln \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)<\left(\frac{b}{a}-1\right).$$

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Try to put $x=a/b$. Also, what tools do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) for $\ln$ on $[1,x]$, where $1<x$ (${=}\frac ba$):
$$\frac{\ln x}{x-1}=\frac{\ln x-\ln 1}{x-1}=\ln'\xi=\frac 1\xi$$
for some $\xi\in(1,x)$, so $\frac 1\xi\in (\frac1x,1)$, which means
$$\frac1x<\frac{\ln x}{x-1}<1\implies1-\frac1x=\frac{x-1}x<\ln x<x-1$$
and this is exactly your inequality if you substitute $x=\frac ba$.

Comment: Maybe you meant $x=b/a$?

Comment: @mickep Right, thanks.